# how to deserialize from GreatSchool API Response

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have to de-serialize from XML (greatschool API) to Class Domain.

URL :
http://www.greatschools.org/api/docs/nearbySchools.page

XML :

```
<schools>
<school>
<gsId>936</gsId>
<name>Centerville Elementary</name>
<type>public</type>
<gradeRange>K-6</gradeRange>
...
</schools>
```

I created DOMain like this for conversion

```
[Serializable()]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("schools")]
   public class SchoolResponse
   {
       [XmlArray("schools")]
       [XmlArrayItem("school", typeof(School))]
       public School[] school { get; set; }
   }
 [Serializable()]
   public class School
   {
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("gsId")]
       public string GSId { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
....
}
```

Calling Method :

```
 var url = new Uri(this.BaseUri, request.ToUri());
            return Internal.Http.Get(url,"XML").As<SchoolResponse>();
...

public virtual T As<T>() where T : class
            {
                T output = null;

                using (var reader = GetStreamReader(this.RequestUri))
                {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                        output = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
               return output;
            }
```

It is return as null. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `school` array attributes.  Try this

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("schools")]
public class SchoolResponse
{
   [XmlElement("school")]
   public School[] school { get; set; }
}
```

Normally C# XML likes have an array name element and then an element for each array value.  By using `[XmlElement]` on an array, the outer element is not generated.

Comment: i changes that code & run again. I got the error as below "There is an error in XML document (1, 144)."  inner exception - Instance validation error: 'public' is not a valid value for global::Homitat.Dimension.SchoolHelper.SchoolType.

Comment: i declared SchoolType as ENUM

Answer (score 0):

As I see - valid values for school type are: "public", "charter", "private", or any combination separated by hyphens, like "public-charter"
I think the best variant for you is declaring enum type like this:

```
public enum SchoolType
{
    [XmlEnum("public")]
    Public,
    [XmlEnum("charter")]
    Charter,
    [XmlEnum("private")]
    Private,
    [XmlEnum("public-charter")]
    PublicCharter,
    [XmlEnum("public-private")]
    PublicPrivate,
    [XmlEnum("private-charter")]
    PrivateCharter,
    [XmlEnum("public-charter-private")]
    PublicCharterPrivate
}
```

Then your class definition will look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class School
{
    [XmlElement("gsId")] //Custom property name
    public string GSId { get; set; } //The same property name
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string gradeRange { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("schoolType")] //Enum declaration
    public SchoolType SchoolType { get; set; }
}
```

But also you should check all variants